# awk modify last string in a select column

Tags: awk, sed

I have a csv file like this

```
abc, xym krg plf, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg gflf, 263, bla bla
```

I want to modify the last string in the second column of each line in the file. Like plf is the last string in column 2 of line 1. I need to modify it as `,plf` to make it another column so it will look like

```
abc, xym krg ,plf, 763, bla
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace it with what?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed 's/[[:alnum:]]*,/, &/2' csvfile
abc, xym krg , plf, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg , gflf, 263, bla bla
```

The syntax is `s/pattern/replacement/flags`.

- **The pattern:**
  `[[:alnum:]]*,`, which means "any number of alpha-numeric characters and a comma;
- **The replacement:** `, &`, which means "a comma, a space and whatever matched the `pattern`$
- **The flags:** `2`, which means "only replace the second occurrence of the pattern".

Comment: thank you this worked perfect. Can you explain so I can learn. Thanks

Comment: @user3616577 I added an explanation to the answer. Also, you might want to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181223) an answer on this and maybe previous questions of yours.

Comment: +1 Nice! I always forget you can specify an occurrence number.

Answer (score 1):

#### awk one-liner:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'gsub(/\S*$/,",&",$2)||7' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "abc, xym krg plf, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg gflf, 263, bla bla"|awk -F, -v OFS="," 'gsub(/\S*$/,",&",$2)||1'
abc, xym krg ,plf, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg ,gflf, 263, bla bla
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried it it puts the extra , after plf not before plf. abc, xym krg plf,, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg gflf,, 263, bla bla

Comment: @user3616577 with the command and your testing data, It gave desired output.  I specially typed `1` in my testing. :) did you copy my command? note that: `",&"`

Comment: I suspect most awks won't know what to do with `\S` so your whole RE might just be matching the end of string. Use whatever POSIX character class `\S` is shorthand for instead or identify which awk(s) it'll work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this GNU sed command,

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^,]*,)( \w+ \w+ )(\w+)(,.*)/\1\2,\3\4/g' file
abc, xym krg ,plf, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg ,gflf, 263, bla bla
```

OR

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^,]*,)( *\w* *\w* )(\w*)(,.*)/\1\2,\3\4/g' ccc
abc, xym krg ,plf, 763, bla
chabc, yfxym krg ,gflf, 263, bla bla
```